# How we can Create query parameter in swagger api in node js?

Tags: node.js, swagger

> Here I have attached my postman url here i am passing query parameter
> how i can create post swagger api using query parameter.

```
http://localhost:3003/jobs/jobSearch?jobTitle=A&professionalField[]=Finance&professionalField[]=Bank&professionalField[]=Insurances
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a one-value array, you need to append [] at the end of the query parameter name, i.e. ?professionalField[]=test. This means you need to change the parameter name in your OpenAPI file:

```
- name: professionalField[]    # <------------
  description:  professionalField
  in: query
  required: false
  schema:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```

[image]